# Почему кеш растет бесконечно?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Сегодня заметил, что память на сервере полностью занята. Проверил кеш, его размер составлял 17 Гб и он занял всё свободное место на сервере.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина подобного поведения? В настройках кеширования ничего не менялось, до сегодняшнего дня такого поведения не было.
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: Кеши разные бывают, уточните, о чём именно речь? Каковы настройки? Где как проверяли?

Comment: Вероятно то, что добавляя значения в кэш вы не устанавливаете для них время истечения (инвалидации). Но, как уже сказали выше, без более конкретных деталей трудно сказать наверняка.

Comment: Проверьте папки кэша, возможно какая то из-них гораздо больше остальных. Возможно какой-либо логгер, дебагер или еще включен и пишет всю информацию.

Comment: I think you just need to specify more details.